# Assign null to decimal MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to assign null to the variable `IdSubCategory` if the session variable `Session["SubCategory"]` is null

Why does the following not work?

```
decimal tmpvalue2;
decimal? IdSubCategory = null;    
if (decimal.TryParse((string)Session["SubCategory"], out tmpvalue2))
    IdSubCategory = tmpvalue2;
```

Comment: Give us more detailed information about the problem and why you don't think that it works.

Comment: What do you get instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually wrap my session variables in a property.

```
    protected decimal? IdSubCategory
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["SubCategory"] == null)
                return null;
            else
                return decimal.Parse(Session["SubCategory"].ToString());
        }
        set
        {
            Session["SubCategory"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method decimal.TryParse needs a string to convert but if `Session["SubCategory"]` is null then your line of code is trying to cast a null in to string which will error

this one : `if (decimal.TryParse((string)Session["SubCategory"], out tmpvalue2))`

In order to fix it please check first if `Session["SubCategory"]` is not null and then try to do the decimal.TryParse

Answer (score 0):

What is not working? What are you storing in the `Session["SubCategory"]`?

These tests pass when storing string representing the ID in the session object:

```
[Test] public void GivenWhenIntegerString_WhenTryParse_ThenValidInteger()
{
    Dictionary<string, Object> fakeSession  = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    fakeSession["SubCategory"] = "5";

    decimal tmp;
    decimal? IdSubCategory = null;
    if (decimal.TryParse((string)fakeSession["SubCategory"], out tmp))
        IdSubCategory = tmp;

    Assert.That(IdSubCategory, Is.EqualTo(5d));
}

[Test] public void GivenWhenNull_WhenTryParse_ThenNull()
{
    Dictionary<string, Object> fakeSession  = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    fakeSession["SubCategory"] = null;

    decimal tmp;
    decimal? IdSubCategory = null;
    if (decimal.TryParse((string)fakeSession["SubCategory"], out tmp))
        IdSubCategory = tmp;

    Assert.That(IdSubCategory, Is.EqualTo(null));            
}
```

This test fails when you store the `int` or `decimal` in `Session["SubCategory"]`

```
[Test]
public void GivenWhenInteger_WhenTryParse_ThenValidInteger()
{
    Dictionary<string, Object> fakeSession = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    fakeSession["SubCategory"] = 5;

    decimal tmp;
    decimal? IdSubCategory = null;
    if (decimal.TryParse((string)fakeSession["SubCategory"], out tmp))
        IdSubCategory = tmp;

    Assert.That(IdSubCategory, Is.EqualTo(5d));
}
```

In this case, this will fix it:

```
decimal tmp;
decimal? IdSubCategory = null;
if (Session["SubCategory"] != null &&
    decimal.TryParse(Session["SubCategory"].ToString(), out tmp))
  IdSubCategory = tmp;
```